# Problems facing whenever I add a filter function in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, filter

I am new to react and I am trying to build an app that adds some items that's been entered by the user in a text filed and displays it right there when a button is clicked. Also, when he wants to remove the items, he just clicks the button and removes them. It's basically a to do app. I have used a hook, useState to change those states. I have 3 files in them: index.js, just to render the app.jsx and have nothing there. App.jsx and ToDoList.jsx

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ToDoList from './ToDoList';

const App=()=>{
    const [item,setItem]=useState('');
    const [arr,setArr]=useState([]);
    const AddItems=(event)=>{
        setItem(()=>{
            return event.target.value;
        })
    };

    const ItemsOnAdd=()=>{
        setArr(()=>{
            return [...arr,item];
        });
        setItem('');
    };

    const deleteItem=(delete_id)=>{
        console.log('deleted');
       setArr((prevValue)=>{
            prevValue.filter((arrElements,i)=>{
                return delete_id!==i;
            })
       })
    }
    
    return(
        <>
            <div className='outer_div'>
                <div className='inner_div'>
                    <h1>To Do list</h1>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Add a new item' 
                    name='add_item' onChange={AddItems} value={item} />
                    <button className='add_button' onClick={ItemsOnAdd}>+</button>
                    <ol>
                        {arr.map((arr_items,index)=>{
                            return(
                                <ToDoList 
                                text={arr_items}
                                minusFunction={deleteItem}
                                key={index}
                                id={index}
                            />
                            );
                            
                        })}   
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default App;
```

**ToDoList.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const ToDoList=(props)=>{
        return(
            <>
                
                <li><button className='remove_items' onClick={()=>{
                    props.minusFunction(props.id);
                }}>-</button>{props.text}</li><br />

            </>
        );
}

export default ToDoList;
```

The addItems/ itemsOnAdd function works perfectly fine. The deleteItem function logs delted on the console too but it throws the error saying:

```
App.jsx:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at App (App.jsx:37)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22420)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**
And points to the 37th line of App.jsx right above arr.map function.

Kindly help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that you are using map on some variable which is not an array.

So I think the problem is here:

```
setArr(()=>{
  return [...arr,item];
});
```

Why not just do? :

```
setArr([...arr,item]);
```

Edit:

Seems the offending one is:

```
setArr((prevValue)=>{
    prevValue.filter((arrElements,i)=>{
        return delete_id!==i;
    })
})
```

Because you are not actually returning the value, try this:

```
setArr(prevValue => prevValue.filter((arrElements, i) => delete_id !== i));
```

Comment: what is the difference really? i have used a function inside it and that would return what you have asked me to correct, i am just new to it please explain.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, there's no difference, just reading through this:
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-store-a-function-with-the-usestate-hook-in-react-8a88dd4eede1

I think what's for sure is that at the time of render `arr` is not an array. So definitely double check that.

Comment: Edited answer, hopefully helps @shrijal

Comment: And no that does not work, throws the same error coz both of those things are basically same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your deleting code. You don't **return** the filtered array. It should be:

```
   setArr((prevValue)=>{
        return prevValue.filter((arrElements,i)=>{
            return delete_id!==i;
        })
   })
```

However this still won't work properly, because you're using the index as the key which you can never do if the list is going to change. If the items have some kind of unique identifier then use that, otherwise you'll have to make one.

In addition, your ToDoList has some incorrect code. You have `props.minusFunction(props.id)`, but you don't pass in a prop called `id`. And you're not able to reference the index through `props.key`, since `key` is a special prop and not accessible.

Solution is to use the unique identifier for your items as both the key, *and* as the the identifier for changing/deleting them.